# Timout on Entry Save if using Categories

Tags: categories

I can't use "Categories" in Craft CMS, after hitting "Save" for an entry with Categories set, the page will take ~5minutes to load and typically time out. Usually, it does save the page and update the categories -- however, this is just not practical moving forward. The entire Craft site is unable until it finally times out the save.

Has anyone encountered this and have any idea what's going on?

I've tried deleting the Categories and creating new ones etc. It happens everytime when saving an entry with categories set. Is it possible that devMode being enable is causing an issue? (See error below)

I get the following error:

```
CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM `craft_info` LIMIT 1
```

With the following highlighted error line:

```
  if (!$this->config->get('devMode') || (craft()->isInstalled() && !$this->userSession->shouldExtendSession()))
```

EDIT:

Turning off DevMode stopped the issue. However it still sounds like from the errors above that this isn't good. Hoping to hear some insight!